# Can the Vertical Pod Autoscalar be used to monitor the K8s api-server?

Tags: kubernetes

Based on the VPA documentation, it only supports profiling Pods created by higher level controllers such as Deployments, Daemonsets, etc.

The K8s API-Server runs as a static pod that is directly managed by the kubelet on a control-plane node.

Is there any way to monitor CPU and Memory usage of the API-server with VPA?

Tried associate a VPA CR with the API-server.
Got an error as "Pod not found" as the API-server is not backed by the deployment Kind.

```
kubectl describe vpa -n kube-system kube-apiserver-vpa
Name:         kube-apiserver-vpa
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         VerticalPodAutoscaler
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-02-29T16:00:32Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    585285
  UID:                 fbbac82f-2ace-4021-aad1-75d8bb4b4454
Spec:
  Resource Policy:
    Container Policies:
      Container Name:  kube-apiserver
      Controlled Resources:
        cpu
        memory
      Max Allowed:
        Cpu:     2000m
        Memory:  2Gi
      Min Allowed:
        Cpu:     250m
        Memory:  250Mi
  Target Ref:
    API Version:  v1
    Kind:         Pod
    Name:         kube-apiserver-c0n0
  Update Policy:
    Update Mode:  Off
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-02-29T16:00:45Z
    Message:               Cannot read targetRef. Reason: Unhandled targetRef v1 / Pod / kube-apiserver-c0n0, last error the server could not find the requested resource
    Status:                True
    Type:                  ConfigUnsupported
    Last Transition Time:  2024-02-29T16:00:45Z
    Message:               No pods match this VPA object
    Reason:                NoPodsMatched
    Status:                True
    Type:                  NoPodsMatched
    Last Transition Time:  2024-02-29T16:00:45Z
    Message:               No pods match this VPA object
    Reason:                NoPodsMatched
    Status:                False
    Type:                  RecommendationProvided
  Recommendation:
Events:  <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vertical Pod Autoscaler cannot find or manage the kube-apiserver Pod because it only considers Pods controlled by dedicated controller objects. Static Pods, unlike regular Pods, are managed directly by the kubelet on a specific node. This bypasses the orchestration capabilities of the Kubernetes API, making them invisible to controllers like VPA [1].

To monitor the CPU and memory usage of the kube-apiserver and other control plane components that are not managed by Kubernetes controllers, you can utilize alternative monitoring tools that don't rely on the Kubernetes control plane for resource management. One option is to use Prometheus to scrape metrics directly from the kube-apiserver and other control plane components. The collected metrics can then be visualized in Grafana for further analysis.

[1]. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).